# Is the game world interconnected?

Tags: resident-evil-7

Can you revisit all areas? If not, how many separate areas are there in the game and when permanent transitions happen (consider using [spoiler tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71396/339050))?
Collectables would be lost when moving to a new location. I'm well aware that RE7 isn't an "open world" game, i.e. sandbox - I want to know if the world is interconnected like [in Dark Souls](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168566-dark-souls-iii/73400474), for example.

Comment: If its collectibles you're interested in, just ask about that. We have lots of questions asking us if there are missable collectibles.

Comment: @Frank: I'm not asking about collectables. See my updated answer, in Dark Souls the interconnected world is one aspect that defines the game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not what I would describe as an 'open world game' at all. There are a number of different areas, some of which are reasonably sizeable. However, there are multiple points where you are prevented from re-visiting an area you have previously been to.

In short, no you cannot revisit all areas.

Now for the specifics:

The **main sections** of the game are as follows:

1. > Guest House
2. > Main House (plus the other areas around the main house, e.g. old house, proving ground)
3. > Ship
4. > Salt Mines
5. > Guest House (re-visited)

The **points of no return** are as follows:

1. > Although you return to the Guest House at the end of the game, it's not the same as at the beginning. You cannot go back directly from the Main House
2. > When you reach the Ship, you can no longer return to the Main House area
3. > When you reach the Salt Mines, you can no longer return to the Ship
4. > And finally, once you are back in the Guest House, you cannot go back to any other area.

Comment: Could you separate areas and list them in the order of appearance? How many "points of no return" are there?

Comment: They are listed in the correct order. I was having trouble combining the spoiler tag with any sort of nice formatting. That why it looks so bad, im not sure how to improve it while keeping the spoiler block to be honest

Comment: I edited the post to avoid exposing users to all spoilers at once. I personally wouldn't want to see all areas in advance and would have checked the first only. - I didn't found a better markdown solution if that's the issue.

Comment: @user598527: Yeah I rejected it because the formatting didn't look good. I see what you mean, but I just think your formatting made it unreasonable. I will see if I can work something out... sorted!